# Как сделать нестандартную фигуру css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Ребят, голову уже сломал об это, помогите пожалуйста.
Как сделать вот такую фигуру в css?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Её особенность в том, что у неё какие-то необычные бока. border-radius углов как я посчитал равен 5px(но я могу где-то ошибаться), но этот бордер радиус не помогает сделать мне левый и правый бок более круглым

Comment: А по высоте фигура должна растягиваться? Там может быть текст внутри или это просто плашка фиксированного размера?

Comment: Это вообще кнопка в макете который я сейчас пытаюсь заверстать
По умолчанию её размеры width: 302px height: 98px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может вам это как-то поможет

```css
div{
  width: 302px;
  height: 98px;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3% 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 3% 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 3% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно. Никогда не слышал, что можно 2 процентных значения передавать. Как читается (понимается) такая запись?

Comment: Вау! Спасибо огромное!)
Если вы можете это пояснить, то вообще круто, но я уже очень благодарен). В ином случае пойду гуглить эти строки кода)

Comment: @Vladislav тут же всё: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius но обратите внимание, что в задаче все-таки немного иная форма.